# Get top value for HTML element as an integer in plain javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some HTML element on my page

```
<div id="element"></div>
```

and I would like to find out its `top` value as stored in

```
document.querySelector('div#element').style.top;
```

as an integer using plain javascript.

Comment: If you haven't set `top` property of  that _div's `style` object_ (when set in a stylesheet doesn't count), you'll get an empty string. You can always get a value by using [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). Or are you simply asking for `parseInt()`?

Comment: there isn't style attribute as well as top property. So it returns ""

Comment: you can use `document.querySelector('div#question-header').offsetTop`

Comment: @Tro I haven't tried much so far. Just realized it was returning a string. I doubt there is any simple "clean" way to do it, but I thought it would be a good question for stackoverflow. I haven't seen any answers that don't use JQuery on here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelector('div#element').offsetTop` if you want the top property as a Integer.

Answer (score 0):

```
element=document.querySelector('#element')
parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue('top'));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.